# very long block in send(), seems to the thread related, not TCP

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, pthreads, rtp

I have an application whose main purpose is to transform a RTP stream into an HTTP stream. One thread is receiving RTP packets and write them into a circular buffer and another thread acts as a mini webserver and answers HTTP request by reading from that buffer (only one GET request can happen at a time).

This HTTP thread, once the GET has been received is a simple loop that call send() whenever there is something in the circular buffer. But sometimes, the send() blocks for an insane amount of time (like >1s), creating audio dropout.

To be clear, RTP packets arrive in due real time, no over or underflow here. The HTTP socket is, on purpose, blocking as it is expected that the receiver regulates its flow using TCP when it does not need audio (enough on its own buffers). But the HTTP client is not overwhelmed by audio as the RTP source is, again, just doing realtime.

But obviously, something else happens and I've observed that on Linux, MacOS and Windows (the code works on all these) and on two different network topologies.

I'm wondering if the send() long blocks are not due to something else than the TCP flow control, like something I'm missing with what happens when a thread blocks in a send()

Answer (score 2):

Get a wireshark trace so you can see where the TCP stall is happening. I suspect what is happening is any of the following:

1. You're actually sending faster than client is consuming. I think you've already ruled that out...
2. The more likely case is that an IP packet is getting lost and TCP is stuck waiting for the ACK, times out, and then retransmits. Meanwhile your sending thread is trying to stuff more data into the socket and it's getting backed up and eventually blocks.

One simple things you can do is to try increasing the send buffer (`SO_SNDBUF`) on the socket you send with. This value specifies how many untransmitted bytes that the app can write to the socket before blocking.  And if possible, increase the receive buffer (`SO_RCVBUF`) on the client side. That way, if the network takes a burp for a couple of seconds, your socket will take longer to fill up before blocking.

```
int size = 512*1024;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &size, sizeof(size));
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't mind that the thread is blocked because at this point its only purpose is to send the data, but you're pointing out probably the real issue with packets getting lost and ACK timing out then. I have to investogate if and how that can be changed on a per-socket basis. I probably don't see that problem with other audio applications because they have the possibility to send large amount of audio in advance, so network hickups are

Comment: Comment timeout :-( 
I have to investigate if and how TCP window and related parameters can be changed on a per-socket basis, I never looked into that. 

The two networks I tried are for sure not super reliable as I can see, on the RTP (UDP) side a lot of lost paquet that I have to request for resend

Comment: You'll want to increase SO_SNDBUF as that will mitigate some of this by giving you a larger "leaky bucket" to work with.  The other thing to investigate is how to decrease the TCP RTO value on a per-socket or system wide basis. (This **is not** SO_SNDTIMEO - that's different).  Since the RTO is a dynamic value that tunes as the connection stays open, you'll likely need to adjust a system setting. Try [man 7 tcp](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp), or an internet search for "tcp socket change rto". There's a lot to read on this topic.

Comment: I'll re-iterate though. Everything I'm saying is pure speculation. You should get a trace of your application (tcpdump, wireshark, etc...) and analyze to figure out what's going on.